# Deleting Posts w/ PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

Basically I have data submitted into a table via a form and want a specific user to be able to delete his/her own posts and no-one else's. This code works but it lets you delete anybody's post. How do I limit it to only your own?

Delete.php

```
    <?php session_start();
include('db.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$username=$_GET['username'];
$query1=mysql_query("delete FROM search WHERE id='$id'");
$query2=mysql_query("delete FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
if($query1 || $query2)
{
header('location:search.php');
}
else { echo "You did not make this post";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: In query2 **$query2=mysql_query("delete FROM users WHERE username='$username'");** this is permanent delete the user information. You need only delete post for specific user for his/her own post no one else.

Comment: Can you put table structure here?

Comment: You should definitely not accept input from the $_GET or $_POST superglobals. That leaves you wide open to what are called "sql injection attacks" Basically, instead of passing an expected id in the URL, a person could craft a url that contains a snippet of sql that could be executed by the server without your permission.

Comment: so what code do you suggest i use to fix this?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right. As written, someone could ruin your entire app in seconds.

Comment: How long would it take to convert all of these pages to PDO would it require big code changes or small things like mysql to mysqli

Comment: also what is the code to fix this temporarily i want to get it working before i start thinking of updating to PDO

Comment: I would also suggest that record changes (including deletion) should typically not be made via GET, but rather via POST.  Otherwise someone might do something silly like bookmark a URL that cause things to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Save the logged in user id too in the $_SESSION for example $_SESSION["userid"] . So you can use a WHERE like

I'm not sure of what these mysql tables are. but for example.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `post` WHERE `id`='$id' and `userid`='" . $_SESSION["userid"] . "';");
```

Of course in the page where the user adds a new post, the code must save his "author id" in the mysql table.

Edit:

And to print that the user doesn't have auth to delete the message use an if

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0) echo "You are not the author of this post";
```

Addon: security improvement, always set integer values that come from "untrusted sources" ($_GET,$_POST, external files) like

```
$id = intval($_GET["id"]);
```

Comment: `intval` is **not** a substitute for proper SQL escaping.